# Can Dracula choose not to move and engage the a hunter on purpose?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In *Fury of Dracula 3rd Edition*, Dracula's move turn comes up when he is in a city with a hunter, can Dracula choose not to move and engage the hunter in combat at dawn on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Dracula has to play something during his movement step. Current location is on the trail and playing any other location card will move Dracula to that location, and we don't want that, so our options are limited to power cards. Let's look at them:

Wolf form requires you to place a location card, so that won't work.
Misdirect specifically forbids using it on Dracula's current location.
I didn't find anything that prevents the other 3 power cards (Feed, Dark Call, Hide) from being used when Dracula is revealed, so this is your answer.

Dracula can stay at the same revealed location to fight again by playing Feed, Dark Call or Hide power card.